# Regex match $-char only as pairs

Tags: regex

I have the following regex for checking a string which have to start and end with `$`:

`^[$][\w:$]+[$]$`

This just works fine for strings like:

- $Hello_World$
- $Test$123$

Now I want the regex also to check if there is a `$` between the leading and the ending `$` it should only be allowed if the '$'-chars appear as couples like:

$Hello$Test$World$

This would be ok.

$Hello$World$

Should not be ok.

I tried it with the following:

```
^[$][\w:($)\2]+[$]$
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work like expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe [`^[$][\w:]+(?:[$][\w:]+[$][\w:]+)*[$]$`](https://regex101.com/r/TWY0Dc/1)? Can the parts between `$` be empty? Also, see [this regex (with `*` quantifiers) demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWY0Dc/2)

Comment: Do either of the above work for you?

Comment: `\$` instead of `[$]` for better readability, otherwise perfect ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider a regex like

```
^[$][\w:]+(?:[$][\w:]+[$][\w:]+)*[$]$
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWY0Dc/1)

If the parts between `$` can be empty and `$$$$` is also valid, replace `+` after `[\w:]` with `*` to allow 0 or more reptitions.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[$]` - a `$` symbol (in many cases, it is enough to write `\$` or `\\$`)
- `[\w:]+` - 1 or more word chars or/and colons
- `(?:[$][\w:]+[$][\w:]+)*` - (or `(?:(?:[$][\w:]+){2})*`) 0+ repetitions of 2 occurrences of:

  - `[$]` - `$` char
  - `[\w:]+` -  1 or more word chars or/and colons
- `[$]` - a `$` char
- `$` - end of string.